# Why does the rule say that,if a^x=a^y,when a is greater than 0 and a is not equal to 1?what if a were less than 0?

Tags: exponentiation

I am an 6th grade student.And just learning the rules of exponents . Please don't close the question.An explanation would be appreciable and I'll be very great full if the question is answered.

Comment: I guess the rule you mean is: "$a^x = a^y$ if and only if $x=y$".  In case $a<0$ it could happen that $a^x$ is not even defined (in the real numbers), like $a^{1/2}$.  And even when defined, you have to rule out $a=-1$ just as you rule out $a=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a<0,$ then the expression $$a^x$$ doesn't always have a definite *real* value for an arbitrary real number $x.$ But we often want something like this -- and we always have at least one real value for $a^x$ whenever $a>0.$ We usually choose the positive of these as the meaning of $a^x,$ when there are more than one possibility. We rule out the case $a=1$ since then we would always have the same value for $a^x$ regardless what value $x$ assumes.

Comment: Could you please give an example of a^x not having a real value for an arbitrary real number x?

Comment: Take $a=-1$ and $x=1/2,$ for example.

Comment: Thanks.Could you also give an example of a^x =a^y,but x is not equal to y for a<1 ?

Comment: @user459284 Well, take $a=0$ and let $x,y$ be arbitrary positive numbers.

Comment: Give an example where a is less than 0,a^x = a^y,but x is not equal to y.

Comment: @user459284 Take $a=-1,$ and let $x$ and $y$ be positive even integers with $x\ne y,$ say.

Comment: The rule seems very interesting .Could you help with a deeper understanding ?

Comment: @user459284 Ask. If I know I'll answer.